# How to show an alert by pressing on a toggle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show an alert when I'm pressing on a toggle, but I want that the toggle not to be switched off based on a condition. This is what I've tried so far, the toggle is not switching back, but the alert is not showing, because, probably, is deactivated by using the `.allowsHitTesting` modifier.

```
 @State var presentAlert: Bool = false

 ListItem(title: ["Face ID aktivieren"], description: ["Schnell & sicher mit Biometrie anmelden"], type: .uniqueToggle, toggleStatus: viewModel.isBiometricsEnrolled) { _ in
                    if viewModel.isBiometricsEnrolled {
                        presentAlert = true
                    } else {
                        config.router.goToChangeBiometrics()
                    }
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $presentAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("a"), message: Text("b"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Open app settings"), action: openAppSetings), secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("d"), action: {}))
                }
                .allowsHitTesting(viewModel.isBiometricsEnrolled ? false : true)
```

This is the component behind the ListItem :

```
struct ListItemToggleView: View {
    let label: String?
    let title: [String]
    let titleMaxLines: Int
    let description: [String?]
    let type: RCHListItemType
    @State var toggleStatus = false
    let toggleAction: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .zero) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: .zero) {
                ListItemTextView(label: label,
                                 title: title,
                                 titleMaxLines: titleMaxLines,
                                 description: description)
                .padding(.bottom, .md)
                .layoutPriority(1)

                Spacer()

                Toggle("", isOn: $toggleStatus)
                    .onChange(of: toggleStatus) { value in
                        toggleAction?(value)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, .xs)

            }
            .padding(.horizontal, .md)

            if type.hasDivider {
                RCHDivider()
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```